# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Why am I only in one group?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, groups

I am experiencing the same problem as noted at:

[Why my linux account only belongs to one group?](https://superuser.com/questions/1348196/why-my-linux-account-only-belongs-to-one-group)

I am running 20.04 and GDM. I've also:

- Followed every suggestion I could find related to disabling kdWallet.
- Uninstalled lightDM (No luck)
- Reinstalled lightDM and switched to it
- Then back to GDM hoping some flag somewhere might get switched. (No
  luck)
- Uninstalled/Purged lightDM

When I call $ id I get:

```
jim@Cheyenne:~$ id
uid=1000(jim) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

but can get the right groups if ssh into localhost:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 18 15:57:06 2021 from 127.0.0.1
jim@Cheyenne:~$ id
uid=1000(jim) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),997(microk8s),999(docker)
```

What else could it be? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.